# How can i get all tables where comma values are contained in group_concat() from LEFT JOINS in raw Msql or with Eloquent?

Tags: mysql, eloquent, illuminate-container

So far i have tried this approach which seems to be getting all the rows i want except for the part where i am doing the REGEXP

```
SELECT p.id
FROM package AS p 
    LEFT JOIN myservice AS s ON s.package = p.id 
WHERE s.category IN (17,7,13,3,4,60,8) 
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(s.category) REGEXP 17|7|13|3|4|60|8
```

If i do it with only one number after regex, it will correctly returns me all rows where 17 is contained, but as i add another value with | it stops working.

What am i doing wrong and is there maybe a better way to do it using Eloquent?

Comment: Having count distinct equals number of items in argument

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Regular expressions are no natural fit for SQL selectors, which is one of the reasons they are not universally supported. They are slow, do not allow index use and are hard to "get right", e.g. "8" will match 8, 18, 81, 28,82, 128, 182, etc.

e.g. `GROUP_CONCAT(s.category) REGEXP "17"` will match only category 17 as long as you have only a few, but the moment you have categories 170+ it will also match 170, 171, ...

Now to your question: If I read it correctly, you have the (correct) selector of `s.category IN (17,7,13,3,4,60,8)`, but since it is a left join you also get `NULL` values and want to filter them out. This can easily be done by just checking `s.category IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, for the first part i agree with you but how else to do this? In regards to your second remark, no it would not have null in categories. Thanks for helping